# Trouble connecting to spark-master in local docker container via pyspark

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose

I set up a spark docker container locally and can not connect to spark-master via pyspark. I receive the following error:

> ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.

**Things I checked:**

1. Ensured pyspark and Apache Spark (in the container) are both operating with version 3.4.0
2. Ensured spark master is running in the docker container and can confirm it is. Logs showed worker node is registered and I can also access the webui at 8080
3. Ran the command `docker inspect <container name>` found the ip `"IPAddress": "172.20.0.4"` and passed it into the SparkSession as follows:

`spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp").master("spark://172.20.0.4:7077").getOrCreate()`

I am running this command on my local machine in a WSL environment. Any help would be much appreciated. I have run out of ideas.

Thanks.